# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method write on channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage) unit test cases in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-secure-storage

For example, I am writing the unit test case for the following method, where I am reading the userId from the SecuredStorageutil.

```
checkIfUserIdExsits(BuildContext context) async {

    dynamic userId = await SecuredStorageUtil.instance.readSecureData(constants.preferenceUserId);

}
```

After running the test case for this, I am getting MissingPluginException for Flutter secured storage.

Unit test case, I have written:

```
test('if userId exists', () async {

      /// set user Id as not null
      await SecuredStorageUtil.instance
          .writeSecureData(constants.preferenceUserId, "userId");
     
      await viewModel.checkIfUserIdExsits(buildContext);

});
```

After running the above test case  I am getting MissingPluginException for Flutter secured storage.

I am getting the same for other packages like location and permission_handler.

Comment: try to run  flutter clean > flutter pub get > flutter run.

Comment: Kindly note that, I am getting this exception only while running the test cases using flutter test --coverage command in terminal, not while launching the app on any device.

Comment: dear @divyanshu-verma Please attach a screenshot or error message with your question.

Comment: @divyanshuverma, did you find a solution to this? I'm getting the same error only when running tests, not when running the application itself.

Comment: Hi @dalonsoa, Sorry for the delay. The issue was because I was not initializing the mock values for Secured storage. You need to use FlutterSecureStorage.setMockInitialValues({}) in setUp block. Also you can initialize values if you want like,  FlutterSecureStorage.setMockInitialValues({"three" : "3"}); and test the read functionality. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really useful. I manage to make it work but in a very convoluted way. This is way simpler! Maybe add your comment as response to your own question, for future reference?